# Bash - How to for-loop last digit of a variable

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I am trying to automate creation of folders. Each folder should have a number at beginning of file name (increased by the for-loop [$i]. Also the rest of the folder name should be build up by variables that are constructed as [folder_x] where [x] is supposed to be stepped up also by the loop.

**To be more specific.** How do you build a string that is combined by the for-loops [$i] and a variable that is called, but should at the end also use the [$i]?

For more details see below:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variables to be used
folder_1=1-folderOne
folder_2=2-folderTwo
folder_3=3-folderThree

# This is the folder names that should be created:
  # mkdir /tmp2/1-folderOne
  # mkdir /tmp2/2-folderTwo
  # mkdir /tmp2/3-folderThree

# The for loop should combine the [$i] and above [folder_x],
# where the [x] should also be increased by the loop.
# Below is what i have right now:
# Note! The text "created-by-forloop" is just dummy text,
# and should be replace by the real solution.


for i in 1 2 3
do
  if [ ! -d /tmp2/$i-created-by-forloop ]; then
    mkdir -p /tmp2/$i-created-by-forloop;
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array of names instead of distinct variables for each:

```
numbers=(One Two Three)
for i in "${!numbers[@]}" ; do
    mkdir /tmp2/$((i+1))-folder"${numbers[i]}"
done
```

The loop iterates $i over the indices of the array. We need to add 1 to the index as arrays are zero based, but we want our files to be numbered from 1, not 0.

Comment: It solves my problem even if I am a bit to new to how bash construct for loops and its details. If you could update your answer with a short summary what the loop does, I will go ahead and approve the answer.

Comment: @Toolbox: Better?